# How to Display Root site List in sub sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, web-partmodern-w

I want to display root site List items in sub-sites. The reason is to avoid creating lists at multiple sites. How can I achieve this in SharePoint modern web part?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The modern experience lacks the possibility to use the standard search webpart. But they have something called Highlighted content. It is a bit tricky to configure but with some time and quite a few tries you can get to an almost perfect solution. Please have a look at the images below.

If highlighted content is not what you are looking for maybe this is your thing. This one is an example made by Elio Struyf: [SearchSpfx](https://github.com/estruyf/Search-WP-SPFx). You have to build and upload the webpart your self.

[image]

Path here is the url to the list itself.

[image]

This results in the following view.

[image]

Unfortunately it does not really exist a modern OOTB webpart capable of what you are looking for. But as i showed in the beginning of the post there are some custom webparts that do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works on premise. There is no way implementing it on SharePoint Online OOTB.

- Open list in SharePoint Designer
- Click on view
- Click on web part in source code
- Export web part by using ribbon on top
- Open exported file in Notepad++ or other text editor
- Search for tag SiteID
- Replace SiteID with the SiteID of the source site (your root site)
- Save
- Open one of the sub-sites in browser
- Edit page and import the web part -> use it there

Comment: This does not work for SharePoint Online modern pages and modern webparts!

Comment: Oh, you are right. As the information "sharepoint-online" was just in the tag and not in the short question or title I did not realize it. I am sorry. Maybe my solution helps anyone searching for this question for sharepoint on premise.